# jQuery drag and drop - how to get at element being dragged

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I am using the jQuery library to implement drag and drop.

How do I get at the element that is being dragged when it is dropped?

I want to get the id of the image inside the div. The following element is dragged:

```
<div class="block">
    <asp:Image ID="Image9" AlternateText="10/12/2008 - Retina" Width=81 Height=84 ImageUrl="~/uploads/ImageModifier/retina.jpg" runat=server />
</div>
```

I have the standard dropped function from their example:

```
$(".drop").droppable({
                 accept: ".block",
                 activeClass: 'droppable-active',
                 hoverClass: 'droppable-hover',
                 drop: function(ev, ui) { }
});
```

I have tried various `ui.id` etc. which doesn't seem to work.

Comment: please notice that `ui.draggable` is not supported anynore. use `$(data.helper).attr('ppp')` instead.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Is it not the ui.draggable?

If you go here (in Firefox and assuming you have firebug) and look in the firebug console youll see I am doing a console.dir of the ui.draggable object which is the div being dragged

http://jsbin.com/ixizi

Therefore the code you need in the drop function is

```
       drop: function(ev, ui) {
                 //to get the id
                 //ui.draggable.attr('id') or ui.draggable.get(0).id or ui.draggable[0].id
                 console.dir(ui.draggable)  
       }
```

Comment: alexmac - replace the console.dir with a debugger; statement, u can then view the ui.draggable property in the watch window.
Not sure why it says not defined. What version of FB and FF? The dir method is standard for FB see http://getfirebug.com/console.html

Comment: Just before console you need
window.loadFirebugConsole();
to get the console to work.

Comment: @MDCore - Never used or seen that and never had any issues myself. I assume that is when you have FB turned off and need to enable it. I just assume all web devs have it on.

Comment: I had an old version of firefox (2 something) the console works now

Comment: This solution no longer works, see mine for current implementation

Answer (score 13):

```
$(ui.draggable).attr("id")
```

...

Answer (score 12):

The ui.draggable() does not seem to work any more. To get the id one can use

```
$(event.target).attr("id");
```

Comment: Doesn't it retrieve the id of the element we're dropping items on ?

Comment: $(event.target) works great, especially when you need to get the element and you use draggable and resizable at the same time.

Comment: Works perfectly, and this is the first time I've seen this named instead of ui.draggable, which does not work anymore. Thank you!

Comment: This syntax is listed as a bug in the official docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/dragenter  (Additionally, it doesn't work for me in Chrome.)

Answer (score 7):

**ANSWER THAT WORKS IN 2017**

A lot of time has passed by, and I found that the current accepted answer no longer works.

A solution that currently works:

```
$('#someDraggableGroup').draggable({
                helper: 'clone',
                start: function( event, ui ) {
                    console.log(ui.helper.context)
                    console.log(ui.helper.clone())
                }
            })
```

Here, `ui.helper.context` refers to the original object you're trying to drag, and `clone()` refers to the cloned version.

EDIT

The above is too see which object you're dragging using the `draggable()` function. For detecting what `draggable` object was dropped in a `droppable()`, the following works:

```
$('#myDroppable').droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui){
        console.log(ui.draggable.context)
                 OR
        console.log(ui.draggable.clone() )
    }
})
```

Answer (score 6):

I tried most of the above, but in the end only

```
event.target.id
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

redquare is right, inside your function refer to `ui.draggable`:

```
$(".drop").droppable({ accept: ".block", 
                       activeClass: 'droppable-active', 
                       hoverClass: 'droppable-hover', 
                       drop: function(ev, ui) { 
                           //do something with ui.draggable here
                       }
});
```

That property points to the thing being dragged.

Note that if you're using cloned "helpers", the draggable will be the cloned copy, not the original.

Comment: ui.draggable is an object but I dont seem to be able to get the div which is the draggable element. ui.draggable.id or ui.draggable.innerHTML does not work.

Comment: ui.draggable.attr('id') or ui.draggable.get(0).id

Answer (score 2):

i got

```
drop: function( event, ui ) {alert(ui.draggable.attr("productid"));}
```

Answer (score 0):

**How to manipulate clone object in any jquery ui operation ?**

Just target ui outer html and use normal html jquery selectors

```
var target_ui_object_html=$(ui.item.context).attr("your attributes");
```

> attributes => id ,class ,rel,alt ,title or custom attr like data-name
>   , data-user