# how to get class/id from ui & event 

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get id & class name of any element from `ui & event` of any function. please see below for clear understanding .

```
<div class"drag-class" id="drag1"> </div>
 <div class"drag-class" id="drag2"> </div>
      <div class"drop-class" id="drop1"> </div>
      <div class"drop-class" id="drop2"> </div>
```

JS:

```
   $(function(){
     $('.drag-class').draggable();

     $('.drop-class').droppable(function(){

              accept: '.drag-class'.
              drop: function(ui,event){
                /*here i want to know the id of drag-class & drop-class element element*/
                     }              
             });

       });'
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging? My best bet is that `this` points to the element you are dragging. Try setting a breakpoint and view your local variables.

Comment: Here you can find an aswer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197489/jquery-drag-and-drop-how-to-get-at-element-being-dragged

Comment: @TJHeuve: yes, `this` points to dropping element but also i want to find dragging element in same function().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#event-drop) -

> In the callback, $(this) represents the droppable the draggable is
>   dropped on. ui.draggable represents the draggable.

Comment: thanks ipr101, `this` represents droppable Id & `ui.draggable` to draggable id then how can i fetch the id from `ui.draggable`. e.g. i tried `ui.draggable.Id`, `$(ui.draggable).id` etc.. but nothing worked out. do you have any idea. even `ui.draggable`returns `[object Object]`

Comment: The docs define ui.draggable as "ui.draggable - current draggable element, a jQuery object" so you could try `ui.draggable.attr("id")`

Answer (score 0):

`this.id` and `this.className` should contain what you're looking for.

Comment: Why not use $(this).attr('id') and $(this).attr('class') since he is using jQuery?

Comment: Depends if he needs the `$(this)` for something else. Why would you wrap `this` otherwise? In this case, he has access to the same thing without wrapping it, hence no need to do it.

Comment: @Py : i know `this` can work for that but it reveals only one element id/class while i want to get both draggable & droppable id.

Comment: this gives the droppable, and as stated in the question pointed by Samich, it's ui.draggable to get the draggable object.