# Dynamic Click on a certain image using Jquery Drag and Drop or other means

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

I know that it is going to be hard to explain but I would like try my luck in hearing your opinions and suggestions.Currently I am working on a project in edge and doing and interactive application.

```
I have image Alpha, Beta and Gamma. 

    1. Currently when image Alpha dragged over on image Beta, 
       Function A() is triggered.

    2. Similarly, when image Alpha dragged over on image Gamma, 
       Function B() is triggered.
```

```
However I would want this to happen to a click event too, where:

    1. When image Alpha is dragged over image Beta and then clicked, Function 
       A() should be triggered

    2. And, When image Alpha is dragged over image Gamma and then clicked, Function B() 
       should be triggered
```

How can I do a way where one image button can be clicked over an image and triggers according to the image that it is clicked above?

I used Jquery UI to achieve the drag and drop. Hope that it is clear now...:)

Hope to hear from the experts and advance thanks!

Comment: What have your tried till now?

Comment: I have only done the mouseover. I don't know how to trigger the click on position on another image.

Comment: mouse over is working??? you have used hover ???

Comment: yes when image Alpha is mouseover image Beta (which is hover), then a particular event is triggered. I used Jquery Ui.

Comment: I am editing the question to refine it so that it makes anyone clear.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#target').bind('click mouseover', function () {
    // Do something for both
});
```

Comment: Hi Priyank, How does this work. Could you explain as it would help me understand better :). Thank you in advance.

Comment: you want the same function to be called when mouseover or click . bind method of jquery will bind the events to element .

Comment: Hi Priyank, What I am looking for is slightly different. What I have achieved so far is drag and drop but I would also like to add in the click event. When image A is drag over image B, and image A is clicked, an event should be triggered.

Comment: Please check new edited problem. I think it explains clearer and sorry for the confusion. It is not easy to explain.

Comment: R u using plugin for drag and drop ? which one?

Comment: JQuery UI. I am not using any plug-in but purely drag and drop using jquery UI

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197489/jquery-drag-and-drop-how-to-get-at-element-being-dragged  may this can be usefule to you..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11631/discussion-between-madi-and-priyank-patel)