# How to get id of droppable in draggable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I looking for solution to my issue . Is there in jQuery UI in Draggable possibility to check for which element of DOM the object is dragged ?

I know there is no problem if we are talking about droppable, here we have option to get dragged element id, but what in other case ?

I need to restrict drag and drop in arrays of booleans. So when element is dragged into droggable I would like to check if boolean is true or false on this particular droppable.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes it's possible.. Can you include a fiddle demonstrating your issue?  That will help me answer your question better.

Comment: Looks like it is discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197489/jquery-drag-and-drop-how-to-get-at-element-being-dragged

Comment: when in doubt with a jQueryUI widget... console log the `ui` object within one of the methods of widget...will find a lot in that object

Comment: the example you invoked point for the situation I written. Getting id of dragged element in droppable, I need different, Need to get Id of droppable when element is dragged from draggable method...

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution for your problem:

You need to pass "accept" parameter to the droppable on the page, like this:

```
$("#droppable").droppable({
    accept: function (source) {
        // return true, if droppable accepts given source (draggable)
        return $(source).attr('id') == 'draggable'
    },
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        // here $(this) is droppable where the drop occured.
        $(this).html("Dropped!");
    }
});
```

The complete working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/akhikhl/3KaaH/1/

Comment: You're right mate, but I still need something else , Imagine: When I will dragged successfully any of element  I need the droppable element in which I dragged another element . It is possible?

Comment: $(this) expression, when evaluated in the context of drop event handler, gives you access to the droppable element, in which you dragged draggable.

Comment: Can you check the fiddle my friend ? Here I think is easier what I need to achive , the problem is that I need to release droppable div, when dragged element is removed from its. This example is same like in my project : http://jsfiddle.net/7aB5z/2/

Comment: I did look at the example. What's the purpose of "droppableAbility[x][y] = false;" ? I think it can be removed without losing functionality.

Comment: The puropse of that array is to store if particular cell on that grid is droppable or not. My idea is to store that values in that array but I don't know how to get event while I'm dragging out element which I've dropped before and trying to change its position I mean release one of droppable and move to another one. This situation should set droppableAbility[relesed X][released Y] = true