# How to get the id value dragged to the droppable

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have question regarding drag and drop function of JqueryUI, Since I already done doing the validation of this, I just want to know how to **get the value of the id of order number** dragged to the drop.

So the scenario will be, if the dragged item throw to the 1 drop box, the 1 drop box will determine what order number is this, is it #301764337?

I will show you my application that I made already and my function for this.
[image: My application]

**My Codes:**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

  $(".drag-wrapper").draggable({
    appendTo: "body",
    cursor: "move",
    helper: 'clone'
  });

  $("#launchPad").droppable({
    tolerance: "intersect",
    accept: ".drag-wrapper",
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      // $("#launchPad").append($(ui.draggable));
    }
  });

  $(".stackDrop1").droppable({
    tolerance: "intersect",
    accept: ".from-launch",
    revert: 'invalid',
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      ui.draggable.removeClass("from-launch").addClass("from-kitchen");
      $(this).append($(ui.draggable));

      console.log('In the kitchen');
      var x = $('button#gather_customer_order').val();

      alert(x);

    }

  });


  $(".stackDrop2").droppable({
    tolerance: "intersect",
    accept: ".from-kitchen",
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    drop: function(event, ui) {

      $(this).append($(ui.draggable));
      console.log('On the road');
    }
  });

    $(".stackDrop3").droppable({
    tolerance: "intersect",
    accept: ".from-kitchen",
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      ui.draggable.removeClass("from-kitchen").addClass("from-kitchen2");
      $(this).append($(ui.draggable));
      console.log('Completed');
    }
  });



});
```

**My Html:**

```
@foreach($customer_orders_details as $transac_details)
                    <div class="drag-wrapper from-launch" >
                        <div class="card" style="opacity: 0.8" id="addStyleHover">
                            <div class="card-body" style="font-weight: bold; text-align: center;" >
                                <h5 class="card-title" style="text-align: center;">
                                    <i class="far fa-user-circle" style="font-size:30px;"></i>
                                    <br><br>
                                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted" style="font-weight: 300; color:black !important; font-family: 'Open Sans';" id="get_drag_ordernumber">OR # {{$transac_details->or_number}}</h6>
<input type="hidden" class="get_drag_ordernumber" value="{{$transac_details->or_number}}" name="">
                                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted" style="font-weight: bold; color:black !important;">Customer: {{$transac_details->customer_name}}</h6>
                                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted" style="color:black !important;">Driver: {{$transac_details->driver_name}}</h6><br>
                                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted" style="font-weight: 300;">Address: {{$transac_details->order_ship_address}}</h6>
                                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted" style="font-weight: 300;">Contact #: {{$transac_details->customer_number}}</h6>
                                    <p class="card-text">Total:${{$transac_details->amount}}</p>

                                    @if($transac_details->driver_name != "")
                                        {{-- <button href="#" data-order-id='{{$transac_details->order_id}}' data-customer-id='{{$transac_details->customer_id}}' style="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#driver_assign" id="assign_btn" type="button" class="card-link btn btn-primary">Assign</button> --}}
                                    @else
                                        <button href="#" data-order-id='{{$transac_details->order_id}}' data-customer-id='{{$transac_details->customer_id}}' style="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#driver_assign" id="assign_btn" type="button" class="card-link btn btn-primary">Assign</button>
                                    @endif

                                    <button href="#" class="card-link btn btn-outline-warning" id="gather_customer_order" data-order-id='{{$transac_details->order_id}}' data-customer-id='{{$transac_details->customer_id}}' style="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#customer_detail_delivery">Details</button>

                                </h5>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                @endforeach
```

**Update:**
[image: Problem]

I already get the value however, when i drag the order_number item that i push is incorrect why it happens? I just add this to the foreach then in the function i declare variable to get the hidden value then alert it.

```
<input type="hidden" class="get_drag_ordernumber" value="{{$transac_details->or_number}}" name="">
```

Comment: If you don't mind, can you share the project on Github? It's really interesting and I don't think there is enough information here to work out how to complete this functionality.

Comment: Sorry for this @ByWaleed, badly I started studying git right now. I dont understand git as of now.

Comment: it's not difficult. Try this guide: https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/ Otherwise please upload the files to some cloud and share the link here, please. Something like GoogleDrive or Dropbox would work.

Comment: There's no need to upload to Git, just dump a few example items output HTML/your css and the jquery you have in the question into a web snippet.

Comment: I think this will help you [jquery-drag-and-drop-how-to-get-at-element-being-dragged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197489/jquery-drag-and-drop-how-to-get-at-element-being-dragged). check this out.

Comment: Hi guys, I just add new update however i got problem when i alert the input value. it gives wrong value.. why it happens